# How to connect two buses with an offset in Proteus?

Tags: proteus

I am working with Proteus and learned how to use buses on this way for example:

[image]

I have successfully used buses on this way. But now I want to connect two buses, lets say I have bus A[0..31] and bus B[0..31] both of 32 bit, I want to connect bus A with bus B but with an offset, for example, connect bit 0 of bus A to bit 2 of bus B and so on. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for Proteus specifically ( I don't use it) but a typical, indusry standard of dealing with "Bus Bundles" would be would be to connect to the same bus with with bus entry points label as:

A[0:31]  with B[2:31],B[0:1]  if you wanted to rotate the bits around.

or

A[0:31] with B[2:31],<2*>C  if you wanted to stuff ground onto the upper bits assuming C would be grounded.  This is using prefix notation.

Note that labelling nomenclature may be different.